# Android: Update two instances of same fragment in one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an Activity with a tabbar and two fragments. These fragments are different instances of the same Fragment Class. Both fragments happen to have a listview inside.

After I load new data in a background process in my activity I want to update the two listviews in these two fragments. This is basically my update code:

```
// Code inside an AsynTask inside my MainActivity that gets called after I load some data from the server
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(MainActivity.this.fragment1);
ft.attach(MainActivity.this.fragment1);
ft.commit();

final FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft2.detach(MainActivity.this.fragment2);
ft2.attach(MainActivity.this.fragment2);
ft2.commit();
```

But what happens is, that both fragments show the same listview items after this update and they always show the items of the last updated fragment.

```
// onCreate method in my MainActivity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //... initiation of action bar and sectionspager adapter here....

        // I create two different instances of "MyFragment" and I pass an integer (=status) to the constructor
        this.fragment1= new MyFragment(1);
        this.fragment2 = new MyFragment(2);
}
```

The headline and the listview items should depend on the integer that was passed in the constructor. But only the title of both fragments is different, not the items inside the two listviews.

```
// inside the onCreate Method of my Fragment class
// Based on the passed integer I show a different title and I get a different list of items
if (status == 1)
    tvTitle.setText("Title 1");
} else if (status == 2){
    tvTitle.setText("Title 2");
}

ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_view);

ArrayList<Joboffer> itemList = DataHolder.getInstance().getItemListForStatus(this.status);
lv.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), itemList ));
```

I am not sure how general my problem is, but maybe I am missing some basic understanding on how listviews work. Both listviews should be different instances, inside two different fragments and with two different adapters. But someshow this does not work out.